# Gatsby not loading useEffect function in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gsap

I'm creating a website using Gatsby.js.
In my component, I'd created animation using Gsap, inside useEffect function.

While debugging, all works. In production the useEffect function not running, what follows to not showing animations.

What I should do?
Any ideas?

Thanks for answers!

My component:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import gsap from "gsap"
import WhatEver from "../../../static/whatever.svg"
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faArrowDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import scrollTo from 'gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll';


const HeaderWrapper = styled.header`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background-color: rgb(255, 216, 41);
`

const HeaderButton = styled.button`
  display: block;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
`

const HeaderComponent = () => {

  const animWrapper = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {

    const [elements] = animWrapper.current.children

    const what = elements.getElementById('What')
    const ever = elements.getElementById('Ever')
    const button = document.getElementById('header-button')
    const icon = document.getElementById('header-icon')

    const whatChildrens = what.children
    const everChildrens = ever.children
    const allChildrens = [...whatChildrens, ...everChildrens]

    gsap.set([...allChildrens, button], { autoAlpha: 0 })

    const timeLine = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { ease: 'power3.inOut' } })

    timeLine
      .to(whatChildrens, { autoAlpha: 1, duration: 0.75 })
      .to(everChildrens, { autoAlpha: 1, stagger: 0.025 })
      .to(button, { autoAlpha: 1 })
  }, [])

  return (
      <HeaderWrapper className="header" id="main-header">
        <div ref={animWrapper} id="header-logo-wrapper">
          <WhatEver style={{width: '100%'}}/>

          <HeaderButton id="header-button" onClick={() => scrollTo('#poznaj-nas')}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowDown} id="header-icon"/>
          </HeaderButton>
        </div>
      </HeaderWrapper>
  )
}

export default HeaderComponent
```

Comment: @TomOakley ready!

Comment: how do you know the `useEffect` hook isn't running? have you added a `console.log` or used the debugger to establish that? is it possible it's running but the content inside the function isn't working in production?

Comment: Yes, i've added ``console.log``. Console logs during development, but not in production.

Comment: so can we disregard gsap for now, as it just adds confusion? the core issue is `useEffect` not working in production, right?

Comment: there might be a component/render issue (maybe in an import) that only warns in dev mode, but fails in dev mode so the component never runs/renders?

Comment: Yes, we can ignore what is in function for now.
In dev mode i'm not see any warns, or errors.

For now, I assume the `useEffect` must be performed somehow differently, but I don't know how. Logically speaking, this is the only option

Comment: hmm, that's so odd. Have you tried removing stuff from the returned JSX? can you reproduce on codepen.io (or similar)?

Comment: Yes, i'm tried remove elements from `return`.

Comment: I don't know what else to suggest, I guess open an issue on their repo? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues

Comment: @ŁukaszStrzeboński are there any errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that the gsap library is getting tree shaken out of the production build. I would either try adjusting your webpack settings to make sure that it is not removed, or include it like this instead:

```
const gsap = require("gsap")
```

Which in my experience has prevented libraries from being tree shaken out.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing this issue and it got resolved just by following the steps:

1. If you are trying to open the html directly without any web server then useEffect won't be called.
2. Only way to solve this issue is by running a webserver and serve the html from the server.

I am using a mac system so  run the python server using the command inside the public folder:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

then open it using localhost:8000